# Fit container inside image

Tags: css

There's a way to auto fit my div inside my image without use of % in my css? I can fit it using % , but I can't get responsive . PS : I want to add an scroll inside my div, that my text fit inside my screen and I can scroll it inside

[where my screen is an IMG and my text inside my div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wXnO.png)

```
.Screen{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 10%;
    width: 80%;    
    z-index: 1;
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 23%;
    right: 14%;

    overflow: auto;
    
    width: 73%;
    height: 35%;
    
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code? It can be done by positioning both element (relative and absolute) and overflow-y: scroll.

Comment: updated with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Screen{
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    right: 10%;    
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

You can use this. As there were no image in the post you have to adjust the values accordingly. Let me know if you stuck anywhere! Happy coding!